How do i get an entry from tkinter from within a seperate function?
I need to get the entry for 'searchEntry' when the onClick function is ran after the button is clicked. I know I could use a global but I've read its a work around, not a solution, any ideas?
def viewData():
    window = Tk()
    window.title('Select Stock')
    window.maxsize(360,360)
    window.grid()

    searchLabel = Label(window, text = 'Enter Ticker Name:')
    searchLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    searchEntry = Entry(window)
    searchEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    
    searchButton = Button(window, text = 'Go', command = menuCommands.onClick)
    searchButton.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

    window.mainloop()

def onClick():
    ticker = tickerEntry.get().upper()

